# How to tell hibernate to ignore abstract method

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, mapping, transient

I have an abstract class and 2 classes that inherit from it. This class has an abstract method

```
@Transient
public abstract String getFullName();
```

this methods should not be mapped into db. However it is causing a problem since I can not run my application. If I remove it everything works fine. So how do I tell hibernate to ignore this method.

Implementing method is the same in both classes

```
@Transient
@Override
public String getFullName() {
    return this.getShot().getFullName() + "/" + this.getName();
}
```

Abstract class is annotationed like so

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Components")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "Type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
```

other annotations are on the getter methods and they work fine. If I remove the abstract method that should not be put into db (hence transient) it all works fine. So my problem is with this abstract method above

The error given to me is

java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception constructing service 'ValueEncoderSource': Error invoking service contribution method org.apache.tapestry5.hibernate.HibernateModule.contributeValueEncoderSource(MappedConfiguration, boolean, HibernateSessionSource, Session, TypeCoercer, PropertyAccess, LoggerSource): Exception constructing service 'HibernateSessionSource': Error invoking constructor public org.apache.tapestry5.internal.hibernate.HibernateSessionSourceImpl(org.slf4j.Logger,java.util.List): Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]

The underlining cause

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:105)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter for property fullName in class com.bomahabo.flow.domain.project.shot.ShotComponent
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.createSetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getSetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getSetter(Property.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildPropertySetter(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:77)
    ... 92 more

Any ideas?

Comment: Show us more code than that (the complete entity), as well as the complete stack trace of the exception. Also, try putting the annotation on the implementation of the method in subclasses rather than on its declaration in the abstract class.

Comment: that would be a lot of code, but ok :)

Comment: if you need more let me know, however other methods are ok since if I remove this method it is all ok, I will now add annotation for the class itself

Comment: Very strange. Could you please post the complete stack trace? Maybe the cause of the error is described lower in the stack trace. Also try adding a private or protected setter corresponding to this getter , which does nothing.

Comment: As you can see the cause is the missing setter but I have no need for the setter since this is transient method which get the value dynamically based on the combination of other properties

Comment: This sounds like a Hibernate bug. Do you use a recent version? Couldn't you use field annotations rather than property annotations?

Comment: I am moving from field annotations to properties since I would like to avoid reflection :) version is 3.6.0

Comment: Reflection happens anyway. You're not saving yourself anything, and there's little reason to go to such lengths to avoid reflection anyway.

Comment: :( but I have read it all over the place that it is better to put it on the methods and not the fields

Comment: @BorisHorvat: You seem to be confusing "reflection" with field vs. property access. Besides, where is "all over the place"? Common practice today is to annotate entity fields (i.e. to use field access). Personally, I've always favored field over property access, even back in the XML-mapping days. If you're mapping state, why include behavior?